# Filter a pyspark dataframe on a constante column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in a hdfs as parquet partitioned by column `part_col` and which contains a column `cons_col` which is constant in each partition.

I want to filter the table with a condition applied on the constant column (for example, `cons_col = 1`). The problem is that partitions are huge so the query is too heavy.

I have tried 2 methods:

- `groupBy(part_col).agg(F.first(cons_col))` and then apply the filter
- `dropDuplicates(subset=[part_col])` and applying the filter

Both of then take a lot of time.

The number of partitions is not too high (around 30) so the query should be fast, but It takes more than 30 minutes.

Which is the optimal way of doing It?

Comment: No, it is purely pyspark on HDFS.

Comment: how many distinct values contain the column `part_col`